# Firefox ignoring document.getElementById(id).style.background?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a checklist so that when an item is complete, it can be clicked and background turns "red". If it was marked "red" in error, it can be clicked again and background goes to "none". It works great in Chrome and Safari. In Firefox, it works well except when you try to undo the "red" to make it go to "none". I suspect it may be something to do with the color name instead of specific values, though I had problems trying that as well with FireFox. Here's the JS I'm using to do that none->red->none as needed.

```
    function onMouseDown(id) {
      var squareColor = document.getElementById(id).style.background;
      if (squareColor === "red") {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "none";
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "red";
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "white";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use `...style.backgroundColor = "transparent";` instead. (I'd also use a CSS class instead)

Comment: Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9vb11v9o/

Comment: thanks @ChrisG, good stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to log the `style` property in Firefox :

```
console.log(document.getElementById(id).style);
```

... you'll see that it does not have a `background` property. Instead, it separates all individual parameters in `backgroundColor`, `backgroundImage`, `backgroundSize`, etc. These split properties exist in all browsers, so you can do:

```js
function onMouseDown(id) {
  var square = document.getElementById(id);

  if (square.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
    square.style.background = "none";
    square.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    square.style.background = "red";
    square.style.color = "white";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="a" onmousedown="onMouseDown('a')">Click me!</button>
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, you could use a class, which would be even simpler:

```js
function onMouseDown(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('red');
}
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" onmousedown="onMouseDown('a')">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, blex! That did the trick to resolve the behavior in FF and still works on Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Hex color code of red in the if statement instead of writing the name of the color. Good Luck

Comment: Not what the OP was asking. Also, starting with "try..." is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I tried changing to hex but still same issue plus it broke it on Chrome so that can't change it back to none. Thanks.